# Where could i find table details on SAP Business One forms?

Tags: sapb1

Where can I find the table name and location as it only shows as a form?

I hope you could help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That field comes from table `ITM1` and the field is named "`Price`".

You should consider pricelists per business partner in fetching this. Look at query below.

```
// Default price
listNum = _db.OCRDs.Where(x => x.CardCode == _cCode.ValueEx).Select(y => y.ListNum).FirstOrDefault();

if (listNum != null)
{
    defaultPrice = (from oi in _db.OITMs
                    join it in _db.ITM1 on oi.ItemCode equals it.ItemCode
                    join op in _db.OPLNs on it.PriceList equals op.ListNum
                    where (oi.ItemCode == _itemNo.ValueEx
                    && op.ListNum == listNum)
                    select it.Price).FirstOrDefault();
}
```